# What is this "CC" (double common-time) time signature called?

Tags: terminology, time-signatures

From Brahms Fugue in A-flat minor, WoO 8:

[image: Excerpt from Brahms Fugue in A-flat minor]

The file name is "Double Common Time" JPEG but only because that's the only thing I can figure out to call it.

Bonus question: Can this time signature be used in either Finale or Sibelius without too much fuss? For now I'm using 4/2.

Answer (score 6):

4/2 is fine. Strictly speaking, it's 8/4 [4/4 + 4/4; or (4+4)/4].

I can't speak to Finale or Sibelius, but it's near trivial to do in MuseScore.

[image: "CC" time signature example made in MuseScore]

See also [Dual time signature of Alla Breve x2 in Schubert?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/94364/dual-time-signature-of-alla-breve-x2-in-schubert), which has an outstanding discussion of the history of this type of time signature.

---

It's worth noting that two modern (Internet) editions use 8/4 and 4/4 (with measures "halved"), respectively.

**Arrangement by Peter Billam for SATB recorders and viola da gamba** ([SOURCE](https://pjb.com.au/mus/arr/us/brahms_fugue.pdf))

[image: Brahms arrangement in 8/4]

**Transcription by Pierre Gouin** ([SOURCE](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/9/93/IMSLP177896-PMLP52928-Brahms_Fugue_la_min.pdf))

[image: Brahms transcription in 4/4]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123947/discussion-on-answer-by-aaron-what-is-this-cc-double-common-time-time-signat).